# How to make proper format for sscanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char str[255];
        int val;

        sscanf("(abcd, 10)", "(%s, %d)", str, &val);
        printf("string: %s; int: %d\n", str, val);
}
```

the comma `,` is not recognized in format, but as part of the string being scanned. The output:

```
string: abcd,; int: 0
```

And because `sscanf` assume `,` to be part of string and not the format, the int is not scanned at all (int the output, its `0` instead of `10`). So how to make scanner consider `,` as part of format, not string?

Comment: You could try `"(%254[^,], %d)"`

Comment: *"int the output, its 0 instead of 10"* The proper way to detect if some value was parsed by `sscanf` is to check the return value. Checking if `val` is 0 is not a suitable way. To start with, you do not assign any value to `val` before you call `sscanf`. Checking return value of `sscanf` should always be done anyway.

Comment: Note that you won't know whether the close parenthesis is matched or not — which won't matter with the literal strong for the data but.may matter if the string comes from an input (a file or the terminal).  You’d need to use a `%n` conversion specification after the close parenthesis in the format string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why cannot I know whether `)` is matched? Does it sscanf handle differently? If it is in format, and in the string, it should match right?

Comment: The `scanf()` family of functions report the number of successful assignments for conversion specifications where assignment isn't suppressed (no arterial `*`).  Since there is no conversion specification after the close parenthesis in the format string, there is no way to know whether it was matched.  If you placed a `%n` after the close parenthesis and initialized the variable to zero, you could tell.  Note that `%n` assignments are not counted in the return value.  In your case, a return value of 2 and a value bigger than zero in the variable provided would indicate success.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but why would you assume the `)` would not match in the first place? I know that the return value of `scanf()` is number of assigned variables and thus cannot indicate whether it matched all characters in format, but it's assumed it does. If it is in the format, it has to be matched. If it didn't the `scanf` function would be ill-formed. So should you bother whether it matched all characters in format, or just the number of assignments (return value)? I think there should be no worry the `scanf` would not match every character specified in format, right?

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  With the literal strong in the call to `sscanf()`, there is no need to use `sscanf()` at all; you know what the answer will be.  However, if you were scanning a string read from some file, it might (or might not) be important to know whether the trailing close parenthesis was present or not.  If it is important not to process malformed data, you have to take extra steps to ensure that the data is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... how to make scanner consider , as part of format, not string?

- Use `"%[]"` to selectively scan text.
- Use a *width* to prevent buffer overflow.
- Use `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan, if it got that far.
- Consider `" "` to allow white-space in non-critical places.
- Test for potential errors.
- Consider sentinels about printing a string to add clarity to the output.

```
    // sscanf("(abcd, 10)", "(%s, %d)", str, &val);
    int n = 0; 
    //                v------v scan up to 254 (1 less than buffer size) non-comma characters.
    sscanf(input, " ( %254[^,],%d ) %n", str, &val, &n);
    if (n == 0 || input[n]) {
      fprintf(Stderr, "Scan failed or extra junk at the end.\n");
    } else {
      printf("string: \"%s\"; int: %d\n", str, val);
    }
```

Comment: You need to check the return value from `sscanf` and compare it to 3 in your example

Comment: @EdHeal "You need to check the return value from sscanf and compare it to 3" --> No.  1) the return value is never a 3 as `"%n"` does not contribute to the return calculation.  2) The `if (n == 0 || input[n])` is a superior test than testing if `sscanf()` returned 2.  It properly detects an incomplete scan (something the return value does not convey given the trailing `)`) or one that does not scan the entire string.  Checking the return value of `sscanf()` would be redundant, unless one wanted to detect a partial scan.